# For relationship between cycling and weather variables: multivariate linear regression? PCA?

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis

Ive been having some trouble determining which analysis to run for a project of mine looking at the relationship between cycling and env variables. I would like to include two different types of statistical analysis, so the question becomes which ones. I am interested in using a predictive model as well, and would appreciate any opinions on gam or other models that I can use. I cant receive much help through my school so any advice of my process would be greatly appreciated.

The data: I have daily data from 2018-2022 which includes Min, max, mean temperature, rainfall snowfall and total precipitation, snow on ground and wind speed. My cycling data consists of daily cycling counts from one counter. I have joined these two together and been playing around with analysis for the past two weeks now. I have created two binomial columns for Precipitation (yes/no) and Weekend(Yes/no) to see if I can draw out a pattern here.

My main issue is deciding which tests are viable. I have logged my cycling data to give it an even distribution, but many of my other variables are not normally distributed. Aside from weather which is generally consistent in its yearly patterns over the years.

My current idea is to introduce the analysis with a time series showing the seasonal variation. Next ill plot the mean temperature with bike counts as this is strongly correlation (and ill show ACF on the bike counts as well). Then, after showing there are correlations (using the red correlation matrix below) I'll introduce my Linear or generalized linear model (not sure which one to use as I have both binomial and continuous count data) which captures about 70% of the variance. I would then love to use PCA to show all the variables acting together as with the linear model I'm only selecting some variables (for some reason adding all the variables lowers my r2). Finally a predictive model of some sort would be great, but I cant seem to find any that work with my data (either rejecting negative or 0 values).

The options: I have run through the following tests so far and would appreciate any advice on which ones to pursue further in your opinion.

- Time series
- Auto correlation
- Linear, Generalized linear and multivariate regression
- Correlation Matrix (Pearson)
- Principal component analysis (and Eigen values)

Comment: Before you can figure out what method you should use, you have to figure out what question(s) you want to answer.  The "what can I do with this data?" approach is unfortunately common, but not recommended.